# VS2022 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace system.windows

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, .net-6.0

According to other answers, I try to add project reference. I open the reference manager to find System.Windows.Forms and add it, but the project reference shows "No items found". So how can I add the reference?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh2PZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WYIU.png)

Comment: Looks like you have a console template.  Try creating a new project using the WinForms template.

Comment: According to your Question Tags, you are specifically using C# 4.0 from 2010?

Comment: It's .NET-6.0 here, not C# 4.0. I have set a wrong tag.

Comment: In Solution Explorer, right-click the Project and select `Edit Project File`, then add `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` and change, if different, `<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>`. Rebuild.

Answer (score 5):

As Jimi's comment suggests, you cannot directly reference `System.Windows.Forms.dll` because it's part of the runtime. Instead, add the following to your project file: `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` and make sure the target framework is set as `<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>` (and not only `net6.0`), because Windows Forms is only supported on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You need change `<TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>` to
`<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>`,
and add
`<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).